# How to charge SLA battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

I bought an ExpertPower EXP-1270 12v 7Ah battery, and I want to know how to charge it.
I don't have a battery charger, but I want to do it with my variable power supply.
I had already set it to 13.8v, but after charging for an hour or two the battery had only reached 13.2v. Am I doing something wrong?

I want to use the battery for general purpose where I can charge it, disconnect, and then use it for whatever I need to. When I'm done using it, I will recharge it again.

The battery has several specifications, including two voltages:

- Standby voltage 13.7-13.9v
- Cycle voltage 14.6-14.8v
- Current limit 2.1A
- Constant Voltage Charge
- 12v 7Ah
- 20HR

How should I charge it?
I'm used to charging lithium batteries that don't take long to charge.

I'm just looking for what voltage and current I should use, and how long to charge for.

Comment: You need to tap into each cell voltage to find out if it damaged by unequal cell voltage.

Comment: These are brand new batteries so I don't think that would be the problem. This is a sealed AGM battery so I can't easily access the individual cells anyway

Comment: Then use CC 2.1A and compute dV/dt when <14.6 which must be a temperature compensated voltage C=IcdV/dt what is C? A needle probe would have to be used carefully. If you can’t do it right , don’t

Comment: I'm still relatively new to electronics so I don't know all of this math stuff. Could you please explain?

Comment: No that is the fundamentals of any big capacitance

Comment: If you can’t compute C show V and time lapsed for every 100 mV rise with CC value in  Question. But if you can’t reguLate current , then you need a better power source

Comment: My power source can be set for constant voltage or constant current, but it takes voltage priority, meaning it will try to use constant voltage until the current reaches the set value, then it switches to constant current mode.

Comment: Do the measurements, list results

Comment: That will estimate the capacity in Ah with conversions But as I said it is like Lithium with CC,CV cutoff but temperature compensated CV.     https://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm

Comment: Just charge the battery with 13.8V with a 2.1A current limit at room temperature. It will be fine unless it's already damaged. In the future, invest in a good 3- or more stage battery charger.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue turned out to be that I had only left the battery charging for about an hour. Over a few more hours, the battery voltage has increased, so it *is* charging, its just being really slow about it. About an hour after I started charging it it had a voltage of 13.2v. Now it has a voltage of 13.6, about 3 hours later.

Comment: Based on the [spec sheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2364/9089/files/EXP1270-Specs.pdf?10653271711015005675) you're looking at between 5 and 12 hours charging time depending on the charge current you limit to.

Answer (score 0):

This 28 page technical manual describes concerns when charging or discharging sealed lead acid batteries:

https://www.power-sonic.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Technical-Manual.pdf

When a battery is charging at constant current the voltage tends to rise initially but then will become relatively constant while the battery absorbs more charge and then the voltage will rise again near the end of charging. However you are charging from a regulated voltage source, not a constant current source, so the voltage source has internal resistance and the battery has internal resistance which varies with the State of Charge, internal temperature, etc. The internal resistance forms a voltage divider with a voltage drop, compared to the no-load voltage of the charge source, based on the respective values of internal resistance. So it is not clear how you would determine end of charge or 100% capacity in your charging setup without some sort of smart charge integrated circuit or commercial charger.